# Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LocalQuorum

Tags: database, cassandra, ubuntu-14.04, cassandra-2.1

We recently started noticing "Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency LocalQuorum (1 replica(s) responded over 2 required)" errors on our servers and are attempting to resolve this but are currently uncertain where they originate from.

We have the following setup:

- 3 node Cassandra cluster Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS (kernel
  3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64)
- Apache Cassandra 2.1.2
- Java SE Runtime Envionment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
- `read_request_timeout_in_ms` is set to 5000 on each node

The queries themselves nor the table it is retrieving data from have changed in between it running fine and now showing these errors. What we have noticed is that the nodes intermittently lose connection with one or both other nodes. We ran a monitoring tool that every few minutes runs nodetool status and from that we see that at infrequent intervals they display status DN for other nodes inside the cluster, but after some time it always resolves itself. Additionally, we ran an automated ping between all nodes and the maximum latency observed is about 0.8ms at peak times.

According to our Cassandra servers host there has not been any internal network issues in the data center nor an abnormal amount of package loss on their end. All machines have plenty of available resources too, CPU loads have been relatively low, disk usage and memory both hover around 20% and swap around 10%.

We ran a full sequential repair task and changed the Cassandra queries' consistency level from LocalQuorum to One which has temporarily stabilized the problem, but of course does not resolve the underlying issue.

Has someone experienced a similar issue before or has some recommendations? I myself am new to all this, so please ask if more information is required.

Comment: Unrelated: 2.1.2 is a very old version and even then was cut while 2.1 was unstable (has some serious bugs in it). If want to remain in the 2.1.x branch you should upgrade to 2.1.21.

Comment: You may also want to check that you're not getting either slowed down by tombstones or erroring out by tombstones. You would be able to see that information in the cassandra logs (system.log) (check all nodes). Also check how many and how large the sstables are for the query. How many rows are you processing? Are you using a partition filter in the query? Is the partition large? All of these things come into play. "nodetool cfstats" and "nodetool tablehistograms" (or nodetool cfhistograms for older versions??) would help as well